# Which one should be used in limit, \rightarrow or \to?

Tags: math-mode

Which one should be used  in limit, `\rightarrow` or `\to`?

Comment: I use `\to`, it's nice and faster

Comment: it makes no difference

Comment: I also use `\to` in limit, but I am not sure whether or not it is intentionally designed for that.

Comment: With a good editor and good shorcuts, `\righrarrow`is more explicit  and you can see the difference with `\longrightarrow` or `\righrarrow`. So it's depends of the user !

Comment: I prefer `\to` since it reads like the math.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They are the same character. If you say `\show\to` and `\show\rightarrow` then both is `\mathchar"3221`. So use `\to` it is shorter

Comment: And in `fontmath.ltx` there's `\let\to=\rightarrow`.

Comment: In this case I'd rather recommend "Use the one that makes more sense semantically".

Answer (score 43):

In your document you should always use `\to` because it describes the meaning of what you're trying to write (i.e. a limit when x tends *to* some value).

In general its a good idea to prefer the use of commands which tell you the *meaning* of the symbol (in your particular context) and not just the *name* of the symbol.

For the very same reason I use

```
\let\lthen\rightarrow
```

And then write `A \lthen B` for implication in logic formulas.

Comment: +1: Amazing just how many people don't understand this

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Or use [\implies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47063/rightarrow-vs-implies-and-does-not-imply-symbol) for implication ?