# \Rightarrow vs. \implies, and "does not imply" symbol

Tags: symbols

Is it better to use `\Rightarrow` or `\implies` to symbolize logical implications?  Why?

Also, if I write `\not \Rightarrow`, I get a symbol that means "does not imply."  But if I type `\not \implies`, it doesn't look right.  How do I get the corresponding "does not imply" symbol?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just a comment: you can use `\nRightarrow`.

Comment: What ever you decide, I would still use `\implies` so that you can later redefine `\implies` to be `\Rightarrow`, but then your LaTeX code still has correct meaning.

Comment: Imagine an equal sign just as long as the long arrow. Would you be accepting it as a relational symbol?

Comment: @CharlieParker I think you need 'amsmath'

Comment: @PeterGrill how do you do that without getting an error? "LaTeX Error: Command \Rightarrow already defined."

Comment: @JohnD: You can redefine existing commands using `\renewcommand`: `\renewcommand{\implies}{\Rightarrow}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\Rightarrow}{\implies}` does not work since they somehow seem to depend on each other...

Answer (score 260, accepted):

To answer your first question, you should use `\implies`, not `\Rightarrow`. `\Rightarrow` is far too small to give a readable result and is not spaced properly. Knuth specially defined `\iff` to be used for equivalence and `\implies` is the same but for implication (from the `amsmath` package). An implication is not a relation like `>` and, therefore, needs to be spaced according to how it is used. Two thick spaces (which are about an en-space) precede and follow an implication because it's more important than a relation. (Basic rule of math spacing: the more important an operator, the wider the space around it). Compare the readability of the following formulas:

[image: Rightarrow vs. Longrightarrow vs. implies]

The first line uses `\Rightarrow` and is the least legible because the main part of the formula (the implication) is difficult to identify. The second line uses `\Longrightarrow` and is better, but there's not enough space to set the arrow apart from the surrounding symbols (the two inequalities are spaced as much as the arrow). Finally, in the third line (which uses `\implies`), the additional space highlights the arrow from the rest and so improves the readability of the formula.

Concerning your second question, the simplest way to negate nearly any symbol whatever its length is to use `\centernot` from the [centernot](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) package:

[image: centernot effect on implies]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

$A \centernot\implies B$

\end{document}
```

Of course, wrapping `\centernot\implies` inside a `\notimplies` macro like Werner did is a good idea.

Comment: Sometimes the implication operator has lower precedence than other things around it, and in such cases, a giant double-wide arrow looks silly. Example: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/869215/164530

Comment: does this work for inserting it into stack overflow questions?

Comment: Why is it that my compiler can't find the `\implies` arrow? Anyone know the package one needs for this `\implies`?

Comment: @CharlieParker: you need the `amsmath` package for that.

Comment: Very good answer. I understand your point about spacing, but I don't understand why a longer arrow is better. I have been using \quad\Rightarrow\quad for many years now and I find it very readable. I still might switch to \implies after reading your answer, but only because I prefer to avoid manual spacing commands such as \quad.

Comment: @brunosalcedo: just like the spacing, it's a question of visibility : the arrow is more important than the inferior signs so should be more prominent (in the sense that, when you look at the formula, the arrow should be one of first element you see). Trying to get more visibility by using huge spaces around `\Rightarrow` only gets you so far since you can't get around the problem that the `\Rightarrow` symbol is too small compared to `\leq`. If you like `\quad\Rightarrow\quad` so much, you could just put it in a macro called `\implies` and thus change your mind at any time on this issue.

Answer (score 35):

I'll answer the second part of your question, since the first seems more subjective.

You can use

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\notimplies}{%
  \mathrel{{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\not\phantom{=}$\hidewidth\cr$\implies$}}}}
```

to represent "does not imply". This provides `\notimplies` that sets a relational symbol with `\not` overlaid `\implies` (technically, the other way around):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\notimplies}{%
  \mathrel{{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\not\phantom{=}$\hidewidth\cr$\implies$}}}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\Y}{\mathcal{Y}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \X\Rightarrow\Y \quad \X\not\Rightarrow\Y \qquad
  \X\implies\Y \quad \X\notimplies\Y
\]
\end{document}
```

Of course, from this point the spacing can also be modified, if needed.

For a quick lesson on `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

Comment: What are the advantages and disatvantages of this `\ooalign` solution, compared to @Philippe Goutet's `\centernot` solution?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: there's just a difference of method: `\centernot` does not use alignment but measures things and then translate them; `\ooalign` is what Knuth used for `\notin` to center the slash on the `\in`. The main advantage of `\centernot` is that it's ready for use in a package. Another difference is that, in its current state, Werner's solution won't give a good result in subscript (but that's easily fixable with a `\mathpalette` or `\mathchoice`).

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: Thanks for clearing that up...

Comment: I was getting `extra \fi` errors with this solution until I enclosed the `\phantom{=}` in another pair of curly brackets. Not sure what part of my preamble is causing that, but just to make people aware of this possibility.

Answer (score 26):

It's not perfect, but I use

```
\newcommand{\notimplies}{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Easiest quick (not necessitating lots of external packages; works out of the box in MathJax) solution among these, IMO.

Comment: \newcommand{\nimplies}{\;\not\nobreak\!\!\!\!\implies}
Works better over line breaks :)

Answer (score 8):

The conventions in other parts of mathematics may differ, but in logic texts, implication is virtually never written with long arrows. Implication is most commonly denoted by `\rightarrow` (= `\to`) or `\supset`, occasionally `\Rightarrow`. Long arrows (`\longrightarrow` and `\Longrightarrow`) are used for sequent arrows.

Comment: This is something of a subject-language/object-language distinction; a formal language will have some binary connective, usually denoted with `\rightarrow` (though historically often with `\supset`, somewhat confusingly). This is strictly different to the informal arrow used for implication between propositions, which is why people tend to use a different symbol.

Comment: Thanks for hinting out the `\to`. I was searching for a simpler way to than to having my algorithms riddled with `\rightarrow` commands. BTW, `\gets` is as same as `\leftarrow`.

Answer (score 2):

It's my answer of your second question:

```
$A \rlap{\(\quad\not\)}\implies B$
```

or

```
$$
A \rlap{$\quad\not$}\implies B
$$
```

whick looks like this:

[image]

Perhaps, it's not the best solution, but it's short and doesn't need external packages.