# creating implication and equivalence symbols of intermediate length

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

It is said that using the commands `\implies` and `\iff` is preferred over `\Rightarrow` and `\Leftrightarrow`, because they give wider spacing around and thus more prominence to the characters. ([This other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47063/rightarrow-vs-implies-and-does-not-imply-symbol) discusses this.) Alas, I find these symbols a bit too long; this might or might not have to do with my "native" typographic tradition (German).

**How can I define implication/equivalence arrow symbols of intermediate length (and I suppose also intermediate spacing)?** (Bonus if the solution is a unit that is selected as a single symbol and pastes with the right Unicode codepoints (U+21D2 and U+21D4; I *think* there are no (longer or whatnot) alternatives), using `accsupp` I suppose.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume package `amsmath` is loaded (e.g. needed for `\iff`).

`\implies`, `\impliedby`, and `\iff` adds a surrounding space of `\;`, that is space of
the amount `\thickmuskip`. Macro `\HalfThickmuskip` uses the half of `\;`.

`\implies`, `\impliedby` are composed of the arrow with the equals sign.
Macro `\HalfRelbar` uses the same equals sign, but the width is scaled by factor 0.5.
`\joinrel` fixes the side bearings (horizontal space surrounding the glyph shape) and is adjusted to the smaller side bearings of the scaled equals sign in macro `\PartJoinrel`.

The case of `\iff` is different, because it is composed by the two arrows that cannot be scaled without affecting the arrow tips. Here the half width of the equals sign is subtracted.

As assumed, package `accsupp` is used to get a better Unicode representation of the
glyph constructs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\HalfRelbar}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\MathResizeHalfWidth=%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\MathResizeHalfWidth}[2]{%
  \scalebox{.5}[1]{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\newcommand*{\HalfThickmuskip}{%
  \mskip.5\muexpr\thickmuskip\relax
}
\newcommand*{\NegHalfEquals}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@NegHalfEquals=%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@NegHalfEquals}[2]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \kern-.5\wd0 %
}
\newcommand*{\PartJoinrel}{%
  \mathrel{\mkern-2.25mu}% -3mu/2 -1.5mu/2
}

\newcommand*{\Implies}{%
  \DOTSB
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
  \protect\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=21D2}%
  \protect\HalfRelbar
  \protect\PartJoinrel
  \protect\Rightarrow
  \protect\EndAccSupp{}%
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
}
\newcommand*{\Impliedby}{%
  \DOTSB
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
  \protect\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=21D0}%
  \protect\Leftarrow
  \protect\PartJoinrel
  \protect\HalfRelbar
  \protect\EndAccSupp{}%
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
}   
\newcommand*{\Iff}{%
  \DOTSB
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
  \protect\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=21D4}%
  \protect\Leftarrow
  \protect\joinrel
  \protect\NegHalfEquals
  \protect\Rightarrow
  \protect\EndAccSupp{}%
  \protect\HalfThickmuskip
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  a \implies b_{a \implies b} \\
  a \Implies b_{a \Implies b} \\
  a \Rightarrow b_{a \Rightarrow b} \\
  c \impliedby d_{c \impliedby d} \\
  c \Impliedby d_{c \Impliedby d} \\
  c \Leftarrow d_{c \Leftarrow d} \\
  e \iff f_{e \iff f}\\
  e \Iff f_{e \Iff f} \\
  e \Leftrightarrow f_{e \Leftrightarrow f} \\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Why do you use `\scalebox`? Wouldn't it be better to use `\NegHalfEquals` for all the commands? One only sees it clearly if one zooms in, but of course it has to happen: `\scalebox` makes halfellipes out of the halfdiscs at the left and right ends of the `=`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt I wanted to reduse the overlapping between the two different symbols, it looked nicer in my PDF viewer.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I guess for printing one should still prefer `\NegHalfEquals`.

Comment: I notice that, when a symbol (e.g. `\Implies`) is at the beginning of a line, the spacing before it remains. Is there an easy way to have the spacing adjacent to the beginning or end of a line disappear?

Comment: @user14996 Outside math mode `\hspace{...}` could be used, but we are in math here. A symbol can be defined and used without the additional spacing for these situations.

Comment: Actually, I've just defined a command `\NegHalfThickmuskip` by adding a minus sign; adding this command manually where needed is allright for my purposes. // Final question: Could you point me to an explanation of `\DOTSB`? (My searches always lead me to explanations of `\dotsb`.)

Comment: @user14996 `\DOTSB` is just an internal marker for the "dots" feature of `amsmath`. It helps detecting binary operators or relational symbols for `\dots`.