# \notimplies command error with breqn package

Tags: math-mode, symbols, breqn

I'm trying to use this [answer's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47091) "not imply" symbol. However I get the error:

```
Argument of \mathpalette has an extra }
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\notimplies}{%
  \mathrel{{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\not\phantom{=}$\hidewidth\cr$\implies$}}}}

\begin{document}
$x\notimplies y$
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be with the `breqn` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You betcha! `breqn` redefines `\not` to have an argument and so it finds `\phantom`, which is wrong in this context.

Add a couple of braces; even without `breqn` the result will be the same.

```
\newcommand{\notimplies}{%
  \mathrel{
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$\not{\phantom{=}}$\hidewidth\cr$\implies$}
   }
}
```

I removed the additional one around the `\ooalign` that serve no purpose, because `\mathrel{...}` forms a group.