# Align the n's in the equation

Tags: amsmath, align

In the following code, how do I align the `n`'s?

Here is the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
n \propto exp(-U/kT) \notag \\
\Rightarrow \quad n  = A.exp(-U/kT) \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this. Put & right after n's.

**Update:** commented by barbara beeton. Thanks.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={10cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
n& \propto \exp(-U/kT) \notag \\
\Rightarrow \quad n&  = A \exp(-U/kT) \notag  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would change `\Rightarrow` to `\implies`.

Comment: @Manuel -- Thanks for the suggestion, mcuh appreciated. A link http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47063/34618 for the OP to make his/her decision.

Comment: the *exp* should really be roman.  `\exp` is already provided by `amsmath` as an operator name, which should do the right thing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Much appreciated. Corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone} % please change it back to your article class below
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\begin{align*}
n                   & \propto \exp(-U/kT)  \\
\Rightarrow \quad n &= A \exp(-U/kT)   
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between this and Jesse's answer?

Comment: @Manuel This answer makes the alignment at the proportional and equals signs, rather than at the ns, which is standard practice: if the relations didn't have the same RHSs, the difference would be more noticeable.

Comment: @Manuel: `\exp` and `exp` is one of the differences.

Comment: @ChrisS And so does Jesse's. Pleasedon'ttouch true, I missed that one ;)